# How to do asymmetric encryption with X509 certificates and C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, x509

I am looking to encrypt files with X509 certificates using public and private keys and send them to a remote server.  How would I do this?  Is this even possible?  How do I generate the certificate and then the public and private key pairs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623189/rsacryptoserviceprovider-using-x509-certificates-c) how to create a [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) from a [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) that can be used to encrypt and decrypt files.

The .NET framework does not contain classes to generate X.509 certificates. Mono's [security classes](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography) (`Mono.Security.X509`) and [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) support the creation of X.509 certificates from C#. Alternatively, you can use tools like OpenSSL or [`makecert.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) to generate certificates.