# Obtaining PrivateKey from Modulus and D in RSAKey data XML

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pyopenssl

I have a kwm ([WebMoney key](http://www.wmtransfer.com/eng/about/demo/help/classic/resp3_02_files.shtml)) file. I use related [Key Extractor](http://wiki.wmtransfer.com/projects/webmoney/wiki/Key_Extractor) to extract the RSA Key.

Extracted data has following XML structure:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>modulus data</Modulus>
    <D>more data</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I need to export PrivateKey from this XML so I can use `OpenSSL` to sign data using that PrivateKey

I found a [.Net solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624695/257972) which shows how to extract private key. But I failed to achieve this in `python OpenSSL`

How can I obtain PrivateKey data with `python OpenSSL`?

Note: I already use `OpenSSL` to load PrivateKey from a `pfx` file using `OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(<pfx_file>).get_privatekey()` But I fail to extract PrivateKey from above XML data.

Comment: Please show us what you tried in python. It boils down to creating a private key from the modulus and the private exponent (`D`) for python openssl libraries.

Comment: @owlstead I am not much experianced with encryption. I had a look up methods and functions of `OpenSSL` but could not found anything useful.

Comment: Try using this function in pycrypto: http://pythonhosted.org//pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation-class.html#construct

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly construct an `OpenSSL.crypto.PKey` instance from the information available to you.  The format gives you the *modulus* and *d* of an RSA private key.  [These are the two numbers that make up an RSA private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation).  The information is complete but it is not in a format supported by pyOpenSSL.

pyOpenSSL can load an RSA private key from a PEM file.  It cannot initialize one directly from the *modulus* and *d* values.  (As an aside, this is because OpenSSL itself discourages applications from operating on the components of key objects.)

The relatively new [cryptography](http://github.com/pyca/cryptography) project, a dependency of pyOpenSSL since pyOpenSSL 0.14, may help you out someday, though I don't think it supports RSA quite yet.